# Using IF function with text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a VBA macro that will look in Column D for a specific value and input text into 3 others.  I believe that I am close to having the answer I need, but I'm not sure what I'm missing to get this to work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim rng As range
Dim i As Long

'Set the range in column D you want to loop through
**Set rng = range("D3:D")**
For Each cell In rng
    'Test cell for CR
    If cell.Value = "CR" Then
        'write to adjacent cell
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "CREDIT"
        cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "CREDIT"
        cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "CREDIT"
    End If
Next
**Set rng = range("G3:G")**
For Each cell In rng
    'test for empty cell
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        'write to adjacent cell
        cell.Offset(0, 0).Value = "FREIGHT"
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "FREIGHT"
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "FREIGHT"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The lines with ** are where I am running into errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the last cell in the range? You can't have just a start cell with no end cell.  You need, say, `Set rng = Range("D3:D"&lastRow)` (where `lastRow` is say `Dim lastRow as Long // lastRow = Rance("D"&rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`), or `Set rng = Range("D3:D100")`.

Comment: You also do full qualify what sheet youre using either. Unless your code is behidn a sheet object.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out--I added in the "lastrow" because this will vary.  The code is all based off of this sheet, so I don't believe I need to qualify it as I haven't needed to with the other pieces of code attached to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set rng = Range("D3", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to declare a range, based on a given cell and its `End(xlDown)`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim firstCell   As Range
    Dim lastCell As Range

    Set firstCell = Worksheets(1).Range("A12")
    Set lastCell = firstCell.End(xlDown)
    Set myRange = Range(firstCell, lastCell)

End Sub
```

The idea is that ever two cells on a given worksheet can define a range. Thus, by defining them, the range gets defined as well.

---

The two cells are `firstCell` and `lastCell`. The interesting part is that you need to declare the parent object (`worksheet`) of `firstCell` only, then the `lastCell` and `myRange` use the same one.